# login/check the username and password from database in Django website using post request

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I have created a blog website where I want to login a user whose username and password are saved in a database table, named "myuser".  I have already fetched the username and password from post request in my function.

Now how can I compare this value from my already created table values to check whether the username and password are correct or not?

Comment: Maybe the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) can help you there.

Comment: Please use Django's authentication - if you write your own then it could be insecure. For example, you probably aren't salting and hashing the password in the `myuser` table as you should be.

Comment: yes i ll not do that with password but it not a problem ,i m learning Django and want to compare those details with my table not the existing one

Answer (score 3):

You can't manually check the password. Because when you are creating a user, django is storing the user's password as a hash value in the database. Now if you are storing the raw password in your custom table which is `myuser`, it's not a good practice.

Because if someone gets access in your database, he can see the tables too. And what he will find? The precious, delicious passwords of all the users.

If you are storing the raw password i.e. `mypassword12345` he just got the actual password. If you use the default django method, django will store the password like this: `jkashdu12321kandsxn!312nasdkhj`, for example, which is the hash for your `mypassword12345`. And now the attacker will see the password as `jkashdu12321kandsxn!312nasdkhj` this which is a hash value of your password. Django uses some strong hashing algorithm, therefore, the attacker can't easily crack your password.

So even if he gets the access of your database, he won't be able to do much except deleting documents. (which is severe but you'll be storing the backup, right?)

So if you are storing the password raw, please don't. It's for your application security.

And now, when you just got the `username` and `password` in your function which is given by your user and you want to check if the user exists or not, you can follow what @MalikFaiq suggested which is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
check_if_user_exists = User.objects.filter(yourtablefield="yourusername").exists()
```

Now if `check_if_user_exists` is true, it means there's a user with this username in your table. If it's false then there is no user.

Now what you'll be wanting is to check if this user is giving you the right password. You can check by doing the following:

```
    if check_if_user_exists:
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            # this user is valid, do what you want to do
        else:
            # this user is not valid, he provided wrong password, show some error message
    else:
        # there is no such entry with this username in the table
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: For anyone wondering .. `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate`

Comment: For anyone wondering what next:
`if user:
            login(request,user=user);
            return HttpResponse('<H1>Logged in!</H1>', status=200) `
After this `@login_enabled` will work.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't store usernames/passwords on your own.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

# Authenticate
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is None:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
else:
    # Ready for operation
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check user by importing model from your model class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
bool_answer = User.objects.filter(yourtablefield="yourusername").exists()
```

if bool_answer is True then it means user exists other wise not.

Comment: i want to compare both username and password how to do that , and also how to specify which table is used for authentication

Comment: you cannot match password because django applies encryption on passwords. Django stores user details in User model of auth module.

Comment: actually i use my own table where i store user info , i think u cant understand my query,

Comment: Love this comment. It helps me to quickly add a feature to a web-site.

Comment: @TSOP1732 okay, if you have the password you can do the same by adding password attribute in filter and then check for exists.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to check whether the user exists or not in your "myusertable", if yes, whether the password matches or not.
2. If active, exists and password matches, use the django sessions framework [most convenient] or the django cache/cookie framework to log in the user and store a session that the user is logged in.

```
def loginView(request):
   # after checking if the user is active, exists and passwword matches
   request.session["isLoggedIn"] = True
   request.session["username"] = request.POST.get("username")
```

In your templates
Note: Make sure "django.core.context_processors.request" is in your context processors in settings.py

```
{% if request.session.isLoggedIn %}
    {{request.session.username}}

{% else if not request.session.isLoggedIn %}
    <p>User not in session or logged off</p>
{% endif %
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you get the email &password from the form then use table name to get all table then chose the email and password from table

```
    if (request.method == 'GET'):
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:

        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        intakes = Intake.objects.all().filter(email=email,password=password)

        for intake in intakes:

            if intake.email==email and intake.password==password:
                return render(request, "nav.html")
            else:
                return render(request, "signup.html")
```